# Counting the difference between two tables and selecting the different observations yield different results

Tags: sql, hive, hue

I am having some bizarre issues with two fairly large tables, where observations are lost as part of creating one table from the other, but the number of observations that differ between the tables does not match the number of observations that are lost.

Table A: count(customer||date) yeilds 1004
Table B (which is created inner joining Table A with two other tables): count(customer||date) yields 1002.

However:

```
with T1 as (
select customer||date as customer_date_a from table A),
T2 as (
select customer||date as customer_date_b from table b)
select * from T1 full outer join T2 
on t1.customer_date_a = t2.customer_date_b
where t1.customer_date_a is null or t2.customer_date_b is null
```

i.e selecting the observations in A not in B, and in B not in A, (which should give me the two lost observations) returns four observations.

What could be the cause for this behavior? What potential quirks could cause this behavior?
This is found on Cloudera Hue.

Comment: Are there any nulls in the customer or date field?

Comment: Check to see if any of the date values themselves are NULL.

Comment: Also, if the tables contain `1,2,3,4` and `4,5`;  table 1 will have 2 more rows than table 2, but 4 rows will be unmatched.

Comment: Why concatenate you lose any index performance?  why not just: `SELECT * FROM table A FULL OUTER JOIN table B on A.Customer = B.Customer and A.Date= B.Date WHERE A.Customer is null or B.Customer is null`  sample data showing our expected and actual results would aslo help define the problem.  What's the PK of each table as well perhaps there's a duplicate customer/date in one table throwing some numbers off

Comment: If dates in table B are a subset of dates in table A (what it is if it is created by inner joining table A with others), then you can just left outer join and look for nulls in the date for A, there shouldn't be any nulls for date of table B in your query result, unless you have null values as mentioned above. Could also write the query like select * from A where not exists date in B.